# Play RTMP streaming and also want to update the mp3 file without breaking stream while running stream in parallel

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, mp3

- The thing which I am doing right now is that I am playing RTMP streaming on media server using ffmpeg command and also creating an audio file using google text to speech.
- So I want to update mp3 file with silence if there is no content, so that it will keep will keep stream running.

I have tried 2 approaches:

- By writing raw binary data to mp3 file but not working as it says content is not accurate.
- Concatenate the audio content with the silence data and export file. In this scenario, I am able to update file but stream broken at the point  while we are exporting file.

I have tried to write the audio file with binary data and also tried to concatenate audio content with silence and then export file but it break stream while we export the file.

Comment: What do you mean by “export file”? Export from what? What tools are you using?

Comment: I don’t understand. You at modifying a file on a server, then downloading it? Downloads are bit perfect. Why is the download relevant?

Comment: I already explain in the problem that i need to add silence where there is no content so while I am concatenating the audio content with silence it needs to be export the content in file.

Comment: But according to the conversation, “export” means “download” so you are trying to rewrite the audio in in memory in a streaming fashion without writing to disk?

Comment: And when you say “concatenate audio content” is that PCM?

Comment: While I am exporting that file with same name it just replace the file which I am using for streaming.  In second approach I am using the writing binary data to file which also not working.

Comment: for concatenate I am using pydub package in python.

Comment: Didn’t answer my question. Is it PCM? And what is saying “content is not accurate”? I have never seen that message.

Comment: yeah used PCM and “content is not accurate” means when I am writing the binary data to audio file in that scenario it increases the length of audio file but not able to play audio in streaming.

Comment: So the thing I want is to add silence in the audio file without interrupting the ongoing streaming using the same file which I am updating with silence.

Comment: @aws You should be able to add mp3 frames of silence. Encode the silence into mp3 format at same settings as the main stream. Then you can just append those bytes at tail of whatever else you transmitted.

Comment: @VC.One I am able to write that content as I send some white space to google in response I got some binary for silence frame and then I just wrote that one into MP3 file.

Comment: @aws Is the problem solved then? The solution being to send white space?

Comment: @VC.One acctually by sending white space as input to google provide me binary data in response and I wrote that binary data in mp3 file and that works for me.

Comment: @VC.One do you have any solution using the above mention scenarios ?